# JQuery - Can't make my animation loop restart

Tags: jquery, animation, loops

I'm really new to JQuery and have read a bit about loops and animating. The idea I have is to have a  and have each of the `<li>`'s inside of it fade in and fade out before moving to the next `<li>`.

I have managed to get the fade in and out working but once it gets to the end it stops. What is the best way to make it start again once it reaches the end?

JQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.fader > li').hide();

var duration = 1000;

$('.fader > li').each(function(i){ $(this).delay( i * (duration * 2) ).fadeIn(duration).fadeOut(duration); } );


});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<ul class="fader">
<li>List item 1</li>
<li>List item 2</li>
<li>List item 3</li>
<li>List item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing this with the right `delay` its tonnes easier to use the optional callback that can be passed to `fadeIn` / `fadeOut` which gets called when the animation finishes.

You can then wrap this all up in a nice, simple plugin:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.cycle = function(options){
       var settings = $.extend({duration:1000},options) ;

       this.children().hide();
       doSequence(this.children(),0);        

       function doSequence ($elems, i){
           var next = (i == $elems.length-1) ? 0 : i+1;
           fadeInThenOut($elems.eq(i),function(){ doSequence($elems, next) });;       
       }
       function fadeInThenOut ($elem,callback){
           $elem.fadeIn(settings.duration,function(){
               $elem.fadeOut(settings.duration,callback);
            });
       }           
    };


})(jQuery);
```

Usage then becomes really simple:

```
$('.fader').cycle({duration:1000});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/VZJTL/

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.fader > li').hide();

var duration = 1000;
var t;

fade();

function fade()
{
    $('.fader > li').each(function(i){ 
        $(this).delay( i * (duration * 2) )
            .fadeIn(duration)
            .fadeOut(duration); 
    } );
    t = setTimeout(fade, 2000);

}

});
</script>
```

Comment: Think that `2000` should be based on `duration` maybe?

Comment: Possibly, or it can be an arbitrary value. Depends on what will look and feel best.

Answer (score 1):

```
var len = $('.fader > li').hide().length;
var duration = 1000;

function animate(i) {
    $('.fader > li:eq(' + i++ +')').fadeIn(duration).fadeOut(duration, function() {
        animate(i == len ? 0 : i);
    });
}

animate(0);​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/mW9xf/

Comment: I tried setInterval myself... found out it caused a slight bit of lag.  I won't downvote, but how long did you test it for?

Comment: @Daedalus You are right regarding `setInterval`. It works amazingly bad. Welcome the new_updated_version :) Sending to hell all delays.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do what you need, without problems of lag(more than one item appearing at a time):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.fader > li').hide();
    fade();

    function fade() {
        var duration = 1000;
        $('.fader > li').each(function(i) {
            $(this).delay(i * (duration * 2)).fadeIn(duration).fadeOut(duration, function() {
                if ((i + 1) == $('.fader > li').length) {
                    fade();
                }
            });
        });

    }

});​
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Daedalus/7uKVm/1/)

Comment: It has a sleep after fourth fadeOut. Remove `setTimeout`, there is no need in it.